# Wait for script to finish before starting function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In a Wordpress page I have a Wordpress plugin (Showoff) that loads DOM elements onto the page. I want to create a way to link to these DOM elements from outside that page using this code:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

var gotoProduct = function gotoProduct() {
    var productID = getUrlParameter('product');
    var showoffInit = showoff().init;
    if ($(productID).length) {$('.'+productID).click();}
}
```

but any link will be invalid unless all the DOM elements have been loaded. I tried various methods posted here but none seem to work for me. I think part of the problem might be that the code called by the plugin is called after the DOM is ready only.

So I need to find a way to wait for these DOM elements to finish loading before calling my function.

Any suggestions will be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try .load() method of jquery to check whether the DOM element is already loaded then call your method.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   //perform required call
});
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Perfect, I'm embarrassed by this as I should have known this myself ;-)